# Storyboard/Modules

Tags: module, storyboard, coronasdk

I have made like an "Asteroid" copy, that works pretty well! I made it with different modules (enemies, controls and background). Now I have also made like a starting screen, where the player can choose to play the game, view highscores etc.

The problem is that I have no clue how to implement this into a storyboard.. I might have misunderstood the use of modules.

I am starting in a Scene1, which is the intro+buttons to start the game. Next, I want to move to scene2(when player presses start button), and that seems to be no problem, and scene 1 gets purged. But when I die, I want to move to scene1 again. Problem is that some listeners dont get removed, and the game crashes shortly after scene switch. 
I guess the main problem is that in my scene2, I have put in require("background"), enemies and controls in my enterscene, which I dont know how to remove when it should be purged.

Ive entered all of the modules and put them in the same group that gets purged on exitscene, but not everything gets removed.

How do you think I would fix this the easiest way? I am very new to Corona and still in a early learning stage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

modules are kind deprecated to start.

Second, putting stuff in other files and calling them with "require" is supposed to be used to call libraries, not code that will run. "require" is not a dofile, or a eval, it will run once, and only once (when the first "require" of the file is made).

If you still want to put things in other files, like loading your background, you need to do a "background.lua" file that has a "background.load()" function and a "background.unload()" function, and call them in appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

Display objects, like display.newImageRect()'s and display.newText() that are created in the createScene() function and added to the "group" display group will be automatically removed when the scene is purged.

Any timers, transitions, or audio.plays that have onComplete handlers, as well as network requests and any event handler that attaches to the Runtime must be removed by hand.  If you're various object you are creating are doing any of these things, their remove functions should undo these actions so that removing them will clean them up.

I find it best if I'm adding runtime handlers, timers, etc. to do it in enterScene() and make sure I undo them in exitScene().  Then if its something that is done in createScene() it should be cleaned up in destoryScene().